# How to search for a word in a file but also show the whole file along with the found word?

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

I want to search for a certain word, but I also want the whole file that contains the word to be outputted on the terminal so that I can see where in the file the word is located. However, when I use `grep`, it will only show the particular sentence that contains the word, not the whole file.

**What command can I use to search for a word but also show the whole file along with the place where the word is located?**

Comment: Asked on Unix & Linux: [Convince grep to output all lines, not just those with matches](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/366/117037) and Stack Overflow: [Colorized grep — viewing the entire file with highlighted matches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/981601/4518341)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `grep` you can use:

```bsh
$ grep -E -e 'pattern' -e '$' file
```

or in a simplified form:

```bsh
$ grep -E 'pattern|$' file
```

Technically this would work too:

```bsh
$ grep -E 'pattern|^' file
```

or even : `grep -E 'pattern|' file`. It says lines with `pattern` or no pattern at all. so everything will match.

I have `grep` aliased to `grep --color=always`, so if you don't you have to pass the color option yourself.

---

With `less`:

```
$ less -p 'pattern' file
```

So the file would pop-up in less, the desired term would be highlighted and you can use <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> to jump around between matches.

Comment: The question asks for all lines of matching files. This will show all lines of all files (except empty files).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But from what I can see, question asks "How to search for a word in **a file**".

Comment: "I also want the whole file that contains the word to be outputted". So if the file doesn't contain the word, it shouldn't be output.

Comment: If you're showing the whole file unconditionally, what's the point of searching for the word?

Comment: As it's only *one file*, It pops-up, you take a peek... either your pattern is there or not. However doesn't `less -p` do exactly what you are concern about?

Comment: I think you may be too literal in interpreting "a file". If he's searching, then he's presumably using a wildcard and means "whichever file that matches".

Answer (score 4):

**Edit: I misinterpreted the question in my original answer.... I have edited it to produce the desired result...
I was only showing the file name in the output. I edited this answer to use that output to show the entire file by using less (as Ravexina's answer suggests)

...in addition, this will only return the files (in `less`) that have been matched by grep when searching through a directory(s).

....and I added `-I` to ignore binary files, they may make the `less` interaction messy. Remove it if you need to search binary files or files that grep may "think" are binary.**

Use the "with-filename" flag with grep to show the file. (the flag is `-H`)

I am assuming you are combing through a directory and each of the files in them. If searching outside of current directory, use the `*` to prevent "is a directory" error with no results.

`grep -HI pattern /directory/* | less -p pattern  $(awk -F ":" '{print $1}')`

or

`grep --with-filename -I pattern /directory/* | less -p pattern  $(awk -F ":" '{print $1}')`

or if drilling down into sub-directories...

`grep -rHI pattern /directory/* | less -p pattern  $(awk -F ":" '{print $1}')`

*I don't like entering the pattern twice, it could use improvement*

Comment: Did you misunderstand the question? This adds the filenames to the output, it doesn't show all the lines of the files.

Comment: @Barmar yeah you are correct, I did misunderstand the question... I have edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see where in the file your searched text is use C flag. For example:

```
grep -C 5 'MySearchText' *
```

will show the line containing the text and five lines before and five lines after the intended search.

Answer (score 0):

To complement the other answers: you can add '-n' to the options to see the line numbers on the left:

```
grep -n -C 3  "something"  filename
```

will show you lines containing "something", with 3 lines of "Context" (ie, 3 lines before and after the one(s) matching "something"), and each shown lines will have its line number appended at the beginning.